# Format of a Memory Address

Tags: caching, mapping, cpu-architecture

I don't quite understand how to format memory cache addresses.
for example:

> A direct mapped cache consists of 256 slots. Main memory contains 32K blocks of 16 words
>   each. Access time of the cache is 10 ns, and the time required to fill a cache slot is 200 ns. Loadthrough
>   is not used; that is, when an accessed word is not found in the cache, the entire block is
>   brought into the cache, and the word is then accessed through the cache. Initially, the cache is empty.
>   Note: When referring to memory, 1K = 1024.

From this i know that for a direct mapped cache the word width of the format would be 5 bits
because 2^4 can hold 16 words, also slot size would be 2^8 because we are give than the cache is 256 slots.

How would I get the width of the Tag field? 
Also how would this change in set-associate mapping and associate mapping?

Comment: (replaced architecture tag with cpu-architecture)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604962/direct-mapped-cache